# php regex for two number strings within a string

Tags: php, regex

I have the following

```
$data = "REFERENCE # 563005"
preg_match("/\d+/i", $data, $matches)
// $matches[0] will be set to 563005 with the above preg_match, however...
```

$data might be equal to "REFERENCE # 563005 & 563009 & 563125". In these cases, I need a regex to retrieve each instance of a number. So, doing a preg_match would set

```
$data = "REFERENCE # 563005 & 563009 & 563125"
preg_match("NEED REGEX", $data, $matches)
// $matches[0] would equal 563005, 
// $matches[1] would equal 563009, 
// $matches[2] would equal 563125,
```

Depending on how many numers are in the string. These numbers may be of any length and there may be up to 10-20 of these numbers in the data string.

Comment: `[\d]+[\D]` i think would work, but you might have to remove the last character of the returned strinf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `preg_match` you need `preg_match_all` to match all the numbers in your input:

```
preg_match_all('/\d+/', $data, $matches);
```

Comment: That did it, will accept your answer when SO lets me. Good to know there is a function built in to handle this.

Comment: Short and sweet, +1. @Angelo please remember to click the checkmark. :)